# How to get Chart js labels in scientific notation

Tags: python, graph, chart.js

I am graphing frequency labels on the y axis of my line graph. The values will be something alone the lines of 2300000000, 5682960000, etc. I have to turn them into scientific notation along the y axis. I have seen that there is a logarithmic option for the scales but I can't get it to work. I do not know my values beforehand. I'm looking to have 2.65e^8 for the values. Something along those lines.

```
    var options = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: {{ labels | safe }},
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: {{ values | safe }},
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: '# of Points',
            data: [{
            x: {{ labels2[0] | safe }},
            y: {{ values2[0] | safe }}
            }, {
            x: {{ labels2[1] | safe }},
            y: {{ values2[1] | safe }}
            }, {
            x: {{ labels2[2] | safe }},
            y: {{ values2[2] | safe }}
            }],
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 1,
            showLine: false,
            order: 1
        }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
        y: {
            ticks: {
            callback: (val) => (val.toExponential())
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the tick callback for this:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
        ticks: {
            callback: (val) => (val.toExponential())
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

example:
V3

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          callback: (val) => (val.toExponential())
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

V2 (Please update):

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          callback: (val) => (val.toExponential())
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: is .toExponential a built in function? Or would that be something I create?

Comment: Its a build in function in js, to make use of this the number has to be in a variable, documentation of it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential

Comment: I have to pass in a variable into it? Or in my options portion the values have to be in variable? I have two lists of values

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the lib becuase otherwise this will not work

Comment: Just updated it to also include the old way (which is unsupported now)

Comment: I have another problem where my second labels and graphs are not in the right spot. The labels for the second graph are just at the 0,1 and 2 position instead

Comment: Please make a new issue for that since its a whole other thing

Comment: okay, I only ask because it was working and graphing correctly before this. When I tried to change it to scientific notation is when it started graphing at 0,1 and 2

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what goes wrong then because I dont think I understand it correctly

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I had to change how I was passing in my values was all. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a way to get engineering notation as well this way?

Comment: Yes anything you return will get rendered so instead of transforming the number to scientific notation you will need to transform it to engineering notation, although I dont know how to do this so you will have to look into that yourself